# SQL remove duplicates at ID and Month level

Tags: sql

I have a table that is something like this:

`ID Date        Name    Age
1   10/04/2015  Theja   24
1   28/04/2015  Theja1  26
1   14/07/2015  Theja2  45
1   30/07/2015  Theja2  45
1   30/08/2015  Theja3  54
2   10/04/2016  Jaya    23
2   28/04/2016  Jaya    23
2   14/05/2016  Jaya1   65
2   30/05/2016  Jaya1   65`

But i want output like:

`ID Date        Name    Age
1   28/04/2015  Theja1  26
1   01/05/2015  Theja1  26
1   01/06/2015  Theja1  26
1   30/07/2015  Theja2  45
1   30/08/2015  Theja3  54
2   28/04/2016  Jaya    23
2   30/05/2016  Jaya1   65`

Consider 1 record per each month which is max and if any missing months for ID then consider previous records fill  for missing months.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide the result set that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Different databases have different methods for handling dates.  The following is an ANSI-standard way of getting one row per month:

```
select id, min(date)
from t
group by id,
         extract(year from date), extract(month from date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried for a solution and came with the following, but you need a calendar table to insert missing rows in the output.
SQL Server Based solution given here

Data Setup:

```
create table temptable (
  id int,
  [date] date,
  name varchar (50),
  age int
  );

  insert into temptable values
(1,'04-10-2015','Theja',24)
  insert into temptable values
(1,'04-28-2015','Theja1',26)
  insert into temptable values
(1,'07-14-2015','Theja2',45)
  insert into temptable values
(1,'07-30-2015','Theja2',45)
  insert into temptable values
(1,'08-30-2015','Theja3',54)
  insert into temptable values
(2,'04-10-2016','Jaya',23)
  insert into temptable values
(2,'04-28-2016','Jaya',23)
  insert into temptable values
(2,'05-14-2016','Jaya1',65)
  insert into temptable values
(2,'05-30-2016','Jaya1',65)
```

The following solution completes till duplicate issue. but to get missing rows you need to implement the calendar table.
you can join with the calendar table and then use output of the cte3 to get missing data.

```
with cte1 as (
select *, 
 row_number() over ( partition by month([date]) order by [date]) as rownm,
 concat(id,format([date],'MMyyyy')) as unqcol
from temptable
) , cte2 as 
(
select unqcol, max(rownm) as maxdt
from cte1
group by unqcol
  ), cte3 as
 ( select a.*,  lead(a.[date]) over (partition by a.id order by a.id,a.[date]) as NextDate from 
  cte1 a inner join cte2 b
  on a.unqcol=b.unqcol and a.rownm=b.maxdt
  )
  select c.id,c.[date],c.name,c.age,c.NextDate from cte3 c
  order by c.[date]
```